# I cannot figure out why my collection is null at some points

Tags: java

I am adding DVDs to collection. And I am trying to sort it every time a DVD is added. I keep getting the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DVDCollection.addDVD(DVDCollection.java:44)
```

Could you guys show me how to fix it?

```
    public void addDVD (String title, String director, int year,
  double cost, boolean bluray)
   {
    if (count == collection.length)
    increaseSize();
    collection[count] = new DVD (title, director, year, cost, bluray);
    totalCost += cost;
    count++;

    if (count > 0)
    {
        int min;
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.length - 1; i++)
        {
            min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < collection.length; j ++)
            {
               if(collection[j].getDirector().compareTo(collection[i].getDirector()) <   0)
               min = j;

               temp[min] = collection[min];
               collection[min] = collection[j];
               collection[j] = temp[min];
            }
        }
    }


}
public class Movies
 {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates a DVDCollection object and adds some DVDs to it. Prints
        // reports on the status of the movies.
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    DVDCollection movies = new DVDCollection();
    movies.addDVD ("The Godfather", "Francis Ford Coppola", 1972, 24.95, true);
    movies.addDVD ("District 9", "Neill Blomkamp", 2009, 19.95, false);
    movies.addDVD ("Iron Man", "Jon Favreau", 2008, 15.95, false);
    movies.addDVD ("All About Eve", "Joseph Mankiewicz", 1950, 17.50, false);
    movies.addDVD ("The Matrix", "Andy & Lana Wachowski", 1999, 19.95, true);
    System.out.println (movies);
    movies.addDVD ("Iron Man 2", "Jon Favreau", 2010, 22.99, false);
    movies.addDVD ("Casablanca", "Michael Curtiz", 1942, 19.95, false);
    System.out.println (movies);



    System.out.println(movies);

     }
   }
```

Comment: this line if(collection[j].getDirector().compareTo(collection[i].getDirector()) <   0)

Comment: You could do much better by inserting the new DVD in the sorted position right away, rather than inserting at the end and then sorting.

Comment: every heard of the TreeMap? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html It sorts your collection automaticly

Comment: how do i insert the new DVD in the sorted position?

Comment: Do not use an array for your collection, use a List or a Set. They grow automatically when required so you won't require to make it grow, that is where your problem probably lies.

Comment: Please use a debugger and find out which of `collection[j]`, `collection[j].getDirector()` or `collection[i]` is null. If you don't know how to use a debugger yet then simply add a `System.out.println()` for each of them. Tip: insert a line braek after each `.` in that expresstion and the stack trace will tell you exactly where the `null` is.

Answer (score 1):

Java comes a lot of handy libraries.
You don't have to reinvent the wheel and do sorting by hand (except for learning).

Hence, Make your **DVD** implement **Comparable** with a comparison based on the director, and then use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

This is a set that keeps its elements sorted by their natural order, using a tree structure : Much more efficient that sorting a collection at each insertion.